# Binding rows in R by keeping columns' names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, binding, rbind

So i have multiple datasets and i'd like to create an unique data frame with them and save it as xlsx. The fact is that i'd like to keep the columns names when binding, to obtain this kind of result :

| Ministry_Name | % |
| --- | --- |
| Ministry A | 70 |
| Ministry B | 30 |
| **Gender** | **%** |
| Men | 50 |
| Women | 50 |

And so on.

I only fond topics to row bind by deleting the columns, but if you see a similar topic don't hesitate to redirect me.

Comment: Add column names as the first row, then bind.

Comment: Do note that, by definition, a column in a data frame contains only one class. So if you have a value like `"%"` in a column with numbers like `50`, the class of the entire column will need to be `character` and math and stuff won't work on it.

Comment: Once you're done moving the column names to the first row, and converting all of your numbers to strings (that will happen automatically, no avoiding it), then you can `bind_rows` them all together. After that, if you write to a CSV, you may need to turn off quoting, it's not always clear to me if Excel will read `"50"` as a string or a number, several factors can be at play.

Answer (score -1):

rbind.fill from the package plyr might be what you are looking for.